# SMPTmail suddenly isn't reading .authinfo properly. How can I fix it?

Tags: spacemacs, mu4e, smtpmail

Some update must've made it so that SMTP mail isn't reading my password from ~/.authinfo any more. It reads everything else OK (hostname, port), but prompts me for my password the first time I try to send mail after restarting emacs. So right now, every time I restart emacs, I have to open .authinfo, copy my password, and paste it into emacs. How can I get it to properly load my password from .authinfo?

In case it matters, [here's my .spacemacs](https://github.com/JonathanReeve/dotfiles/blob/master/dotfiles/.spacemacs).

Comment: Try a fresh install of spacemacs and just the absolute minimum settings needed to test SMTP mail and your .authinfo.  If it works with a barebones install of spacemacs, then know that something in your user-configuration (or a subsequently installed package) is the problem.  If it does not work with a barebones install of spacemacs, then you will need to try with a barebones installation of Emacs without spacemacs ...

Comment: (1) Make sure your "~/.authinfo" file still has the required information. (2) Inspect the output of `M-: (get-authinfo "gcal.api" "9999")`. Does that output contain your password? If that is not the case then probably the `netrc` package causes the problem. They made recently a tiny change regarding the clang compiler beside the copyright adaptions for 2018.